# Why is $\mathbb{Q}_p\langle T\rangle/\mathfrak{m}$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

$\mathbb{Q}_p\langle T\rangle$ is the Tate algebra, which, by definition, is the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-algebra of power series in $\mathbb{Q}_p[[T]]$ whose coefficients tend to zero. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}_p\langle T\rangle$. How can you show that $\mathbb{Q}_p\langle T\rangle /\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: How much do you know already? Where are you in the study of local fields?

Comment: This is included in https://kskedlaya.org/18.727/tate-algebras.pdf, [Topics in Algebraic Geometry (rigid analytic geometry), Kiran S. Kedlaya, Fall 2004, Proposition 6, page 5], stating that the Krull dimension of the Tate algebra in $n$ variables is $n$. Wonderful exposition!

Comment: @dan_fulea That's very helpful, thanks!  \@Lubin this is just the first time I see Tate algebra, maybe I should've asked for reference instead :)